# How can I grant access to videos to authorized users only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

For example, only paying users should be allowed to view a video.

There is a plugin for that or is it all written from scratch?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to reach. Do you want to authorize if users have access to a resource (in your example video stored inside the rails application)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) and [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) are two popular authentication mechanisms. Either could be used to restrict access to particular actions based on logged-in status.

If you need a finer-grained authorization system, [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) provides a permissions system.

There are others, but these are quite popular.